# How to simulate keystrokes on not connected Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a Windows VPS running remotely and use Remote Desktop Connection to do some macros everyday. I have a Windows app that simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks using native Windows API , to do the job.

Everything works fine as long as there is someone connected on the VPS using RDC.

If i close the Remote Desktop Connection, although the machine is still alive and running, all my macros stop to work.

I presume it's because Windows understands that there isnt someone connected, so the keyboard and mouse won't work.

Is there any workaround for this situation ?

Thanks